# Extract substrings with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!
```

And I need to extract the name - BIANCA and the text that is at the end into two variables.
I tried to do somthen like this:

```
dialogue = "L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!"
name : str = ""
line : str = ""
name = re.findall('^L.*\s(.+?)\s.*', dialogue)
```

but I'm a little confused about using regular expression.
How can I solve this using regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: By "Text that is at the end" do you mean "They do not!" ?

Comment: `name, line = dialogue.rsplit(' +++$+++ ', 2)[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[ \t]([^+]+)[ \t]\+{3}\$\+{3}[ \t]+([^+]+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkrElF/1/)

Python:

```
import re

dialogue = "L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!"

>>> re.findall(r'[ \t]([^+]+)[ \t]\+{3}\$\+{3}[ \t]+([^+]+)$', dialogue)
[('BIANCA', 'They do not!')]
```

You can also split and slice:

```
>>> re.split(r'[ \t]\+{3}\$\+{3}[ \t]', dialogue)[-2:]
['BIANCA', ' They do not!']
```

But split and slice does not gracefully fail if `+++$+++` is not found; the search pattern above does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without `re`

```
data = "L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!"
parts = data.split('+++$+++')
print(parts[-2].strip())
print(parts[-1].strip())
```

output

```
BIANCA
They do not!
```

Comment: Add spaces to divider `data.rsplit(' +++$+++ ', 2)` and `str.strip()` is not needed, so you can do `print(*data.rsplit(' +++$+++ ', 2)[1:], sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1):

You could match `L` at the start of the string, and use a quantifier `{n}` to set the number of occurrences to match `+++$+++` followed by non whitespace characters.

```
^L\S*(?: \+{3}\$\+{3} \S+){2} \+{3}\$\+{3} (\S+) \+{3}\$\+{3} (.+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `L\S*` Match `L` followed by optional non whitespace chars
- `(?: \+{3}\$\+{3} \S+){2}` Using a quantifier, repeat 2 times matching the delimiter followed by 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\+{3}\$\+{3}` Match the delimiter
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars to match `BIANCA`
- `\+{3}\$\+{3}`  Match the delimiter
- `(.+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except a newline to match `They do not!`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuAPr7/1)